# WooCommerce Rest API not returning 'product_url'

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am currently using this API: https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library to automatically keep my products upto date from several different data feeds.

I need to check the endpoint URLs

I am currently adding products / updating them fine but I need the URL for external products to see if the product is still listed on the destination site. If I print out all the information stored on a product using:

```
print_r( $client->products->get(124) );
```

it doesn't return the product_url field.

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Comment: Can't you just use the product ID in this case? `http://example.com/?p=123`?

Comment: I am using the product ID - 124 = the product ID in this case. Using the code in the OP it prints out all of the information for the product but not the external product_url.

Comment: Products in WooCommerce as self contained entities, WooCommerce is only aware of its existence in its own database. If the external URL from where the product was imported is not stored in WooCommerce database as product meta, there's no way for WooCommerce to return that back.

Comment: Hi Anand, the product_url property is stored within the database. When I import all of my products via the datafeed I have an affiliate URL which is tied to the 'product_url' property within Woocommerce - this is then persisted to the database.